# Are there any HTTP-clients(packages) in node.js that do not use promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Need to get data from a url, but write it in an object or a variable.
Example:

```
var form = method(url).body
console.log(form)
// {
//     data: {...}
// }
```

Comment: What does your question title have to do with the rest of your question? Why don't you want to use a promise-based utility? They're generally considered much better than a callback-based option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the async/await syntax, functions using promises can process results in a similar way to synchronous ones.

```
var form = await methodUsingPrmoise(url)
console.log(form.data)
// {
//     data: {...}
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use RxJs and work with Observables rather than promises. But you need something that is async by nature. jQuery used to have a synchronous option but I would highly recommend against using it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question literally, sure, there are plenty of node HTTP clients that don't use promises.  [request](https://github.com/request/request/) is (was) the most popular.  They are still async though — instead of promises, they use callbacks.

Reading in to your question a bit, it looks like what you're attempting to ask is "are there synchronous HTTP clients in node?" to which the answer is an unqualified **no**.

node's network APIs do not expose synchronous functions, so it's not possible to create a synchronous HTTP client that would enable writing the code in your example.

Promises + `await` are your friend, since they allow you to write code that *looks* synchronous even though it's really async under the covers.

```
var form = (await method(url)).body;
console.log(form);
```